# How to rotate light with camera in Three.js & OrbitControls.js

Tags: three.js

I tried to use camera.add(light),but it doesn't work...it didn't show..
 Actually, i just want to use orbit control on only few things in the scene, and rotate others with camera, but i don't no how to do that with OrbitControls.js

please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Your question requires more details, like what kind of light are you using. It would also help if you can share your code, or create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Add the light to the camera, add the camera to the scene.

And yes, TheJim01 is right, you'd better provide a working demo, that shows the problem.